# Expire UIL cached images after 2 days in android

Tags: android, image, caching, universal-image-loader

I am using Universal Image Library (UIL) to load images in my application.

Now problem is that I can have different images on same URL. I mean today I have a cat picture in a URL and tomorrow I might have a dog picture on same URL. So I want to check that if cached image is 2 days old then delete it and download the image again.

This is my configuration.

```
    File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(this, "FriendListCache");
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
        // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
        .diskCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) 
        .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
        .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

And this is image loading options.

```
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
     options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.medium_load)
    .cacheInMemory(true)
    .cacheOnDisk(true)
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
    .decodingOptions(resizeOptions)
    .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(160))
    .build();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UIL provide **LimitedAgeDiscCache** option for your requirement.

**LimitedAgeDiscCache** (Size-unlimited cache with limited files' lifetime. If age of cached file exceeds defined limit then it will be deleted from cache.)

```
.discCache(new LimitedAgeDiscCache(cacheDir, 14400))
```

Comment: is 14400 is in seconds? Because for checking I inserted just 300 seconds yesterday but this doesn't changes the photo after 300 seconds. But today it is changed, that means it worked but not after 300 seconds.

Comment: yes, its in seconds based on documentation `public LimitedAgeDiscCache(java.io.File cacheDir, long maxAge)` where "`maxAge` - Max file age (in seconds). If file age will exceed this value then it'll be removed on next treatment (and therefore be reloaded)."
http://javadox.com/com.nostra13.universalimageloader/universal-image-loader/1.9.0/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/cache/disc/impl/LimitedAgeDiscCache.html